# Is it possible to use Findcomponet method in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

There are seven combo box on form

I want to add the item in each combo box. But i don't want to manual mode for add the item.

I want to use the ForLoop to add the item.

I try like this, but second line is get exception occurred.

Dim cmb_Temp as ComboBox  = New ComboBox
cmb_Temp.Name = "cmb_a" + "7" <- exception

so, I don't know about how to handling the ForLoop to add the item.

is it impossible in vb.net?.

is it use the FindeComponet method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, you can use Controls.Find() like this:

```
    Dim matches() As Control
    For i As Integer = 1 To 7
        matches = Me.Controls.Find("cmb_a" & i, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is ComboBox Then
            Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(matches(0), ComboBox)
            cb.Items.Add("SomeItem")
        End If
    Next
```